# Document Object Model function to take an array of links from a database and process them one by one

Tags: php, domdocument

I've been trying to troubleshoot a program I'm trying to build and I've managed to figure out what is causing the problem, however to fix it I have been unsuccessful.

I am using the document object model function in php to take an array of links from a database and process them one by one, however it appears that in the @$doc->loadHTMLFile("$alllinks"); line there is a problem with this function accepting array values from the database.

what I find puzzling however is if I create a general array it works, but from the database (or a few other methods) it simply fails.

here is the version that works:

```
<?php session_start();


// EDIT: Use a custom function to do the
// reverse of SORT_NUMERIC with asort
function height_compare($a1, $b1)
{
    if ($a1 == $b1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a1 > $b1) ? -1 : 1;
}

$all_links = array('http://example.com/klvvobj','http://example.net/s/109228626');

foreach($all_links as $alllinks){
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Okay this is HTML is kind of screwy
// So we're going to suppress errors
@$doc->loadHTMLFile("$alllinks");

// Get all images
$images_list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

$images = array();
foreach($images_list as $image) {

  // Get the src attribute
  $image_source = $image->getAttribute('src');

  if (substr($image_source,0,7)=="http://"){
  $image_size_info = getimagesize($image_source);

  $images[$image_source] = $image_size_info[1];
  print_r($images);
  }
}


// Do a numeric sort on the height
uasort($images, "height_compare");
$tallest_image = array_slice($images, 0,1);
$mainimg = key($tallest_image);

echo "<img src='$mainimg' />";

}
print_r($images);

?>
```

and here is the version that fails:

```
<?php session_start();

include 'functions.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links");

        function height_compare($a1, $b1)
{
    if ($a1 == $b1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a1 > $b1) ? -1 : 1;
}

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$link = $result['link'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// Okay this is HTML is kind of screwy
// So we're going to suppress errors
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($link);

// Get all images
$images_list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

$images = array();
foreach($images_list as $image) {

  // Get the src attribute
  $image_source = $image->getAttribute('src');

  if (substr($image_source,0,7)=="http://"){
  $image_size_info = getimagesize($image_source);

  $images[$image_source] = $image_size_info[1];
  print_r($images);
  }
}


// Do a numeric sort on the height
uasort($images, "height_compare");
$tallest_image = array_slice($images, 0,1);
$mainimg = key($tallest_image);

echo "<img src='$mainimg' />";

}

                     echo '<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>';

?>
```

Comment: did that really just happen??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

`@$doc->loadHTMLFile("'$link'");`

even if `$link` contains a correct/readable address, the result will be something like:

`@$doc->loadHTMLFile("'http://...'");`

and `'http://...'` is not a correct address.

(See the `'`)

Change it to:

`@$doc->loadHTMLFile($link);`

---

Also, please don't use the `@` for error surpressing: Use

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

and

```
libxml_get_errors();
```

when dealing with problematic xml/html. See http://php.net/manual/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php

---

Another addition:

You don't need the sort stuff. If you just want the "tallest images" use:

```
$mainimg = array_search(max($images), $images);
```

Comment: I had actually tried this without quotes, with single quotes and with double quotes and none worked shockingly

Comment: @edmund You generally don't need any quotes arround variables at all (if you're just passing them arround). Quotes are only need on string concatenation. If you want to cast a variable to a string use `(string)$yourVar ...`.

Comment: @edmun then please edit your post to include the actual code you're using.

Comment: just edited, this was the original version I attempted actually, but like I said, with or without quotes the variables just refuse to pass for some reason

Comment: will implement your methods for error suppressing, thanks for the tip

Comment: @edmund Do you get any errors dislayed / Have you checked the contents of `$link` manually? Like `echo $link;` (for debugging)

Comment: this is the error message im currently getting   Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity " http://lockerz.com/s/11"  on line 21

Comment: @edmund Are the `"` stored in your db? If yes, than that's your problem. (having links which are syntactically incorrect). If you can't change that in the db, try: `$link = trim($link, ' "');`

Comment: @edmund From what I see, the link you gave (without the double quotes) gives a 404 response. This could also be problematic. ;)

Comment: oh my god! the trim function solved it! incredible! thanks so much for your help, you are a genius!